# Load HTML local template files with Backbone in a Phonegap/Cordova application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, backbone.js

I have this piece of code where I want to load my HTML template from an external files inside a view folder.

```
var InputView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'form',

  template: _.template($.get('views/inputCapo.html')),

  render: function(){
    app.$el.append(this.template);
    return this;
  }

});
```

`app` is the main view of my application, I know the issue with the XHR request with local files where I can't load that for security reason.

I know that this is a problem with browsers, but with phonegap application the issue is the same?

Which is the best alternative to accomplish the same feature keeping HTML files separate from scripts?

I have already saw `require.js` and `text.js` library for loading HTML files without `$.get` but there is again the same dependency on XHR restrictions.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to precompile your templates during build?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you talking about Grunt or something else?

Comment: Grunt is one option, yes, but many ways to precompile templates, which is better because then everything is bundled. The only reason not to do so is if you have very large templates that will only be called rarely.

Comment: I understand, but with template file what do you mean? HTML files concatenated with grunt?

Comment: Behind the scenes it will compile the templates into strings keyed by path, so that `_.template('views/inputCapo')` gives you your compiled template.

Comment: Mmm you are talking again about grunt? Could you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

It can be much more performant to precompile your templates, rather than requesting them dynamically. One way to do this is to use Grunt to build them into a JST namespace - https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jst.

Then in your Gruntfile, something like this:

```
jst: {
  compile: {
    files: {
      "path/to/compiled/templates.js": ["path/to/source/**/*.html"]
    }
  }
}
```

In your Backbone View:

```
var InputView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'form',

  template: JST['views/inputCapo'],

  render: function(){
    app.$el.append(this.template());
    return this;
  }

});
```

Then just be sure to include the `path/to/compiled/templates.js` script in your index.html file before your Backbone views.